# "Поступ" чи "прогрес" хвороби?

Tags: вибір-слова, синоніми

Ми можемо сказати - "Ваш геморой прогресує", чи можна, натомість, сказати - "Ваш геморой поступає"?

[*Прогрес*](http://sum.in.ua/s/proghres) має значення:

> Розвиток по висхідній лінії, удосконалення в цьому процесі, перехід
>   від нижчого до вищого, від простого до більш складного;

Відповідно і [*поступ*](http://sum.in.ua/s/Postup) має значення:

> **перен.** Поступальний розвиток по висхідній лінії, перехід від нижчого
>   рівня до вищого; прогрес.

Ні слова [*прогресує*](http://sum.in.ua/s/proghresuje), ні слова [*поступає*](http://sum.in.ua/s/postupaje) я у словнику не знайшов.
Яке дієслово і його синонімі варто вживати у разі погіршення хвороби?

Comment: Дієслова в словниках треба шукати _в неозначеній формі (в інфінітиві)_, а не в 1-й особі однини теперішнього часу, як це робили ви. В неозначеній формі в СУМі є й [прогресувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/proghresuvaty), й [поступати](http://sum.in.ua/s/postupaty) (значення 2). А ще ж можна сказати _розвивається_.

Comment: @Yellow Sky, я вважаю, що вам варто зробити повноцінну відповідь на базі свого коментаря.

Answer (score 2):

На практиці люди вживають:

- поступ хвороби:

  > Від 1941 року помітний вже був поступ хвороби на організм, на лиці і на пригнобленому настрої письменниці. <sub>//[«Ольга Кобилянська в критиці та спогадах», державне видавництво художньої літератури, 1963, с. 431](//books.google.com.ua/books?id=s1QhAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF+%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%22)</sub>
  >
  > Вона з матір'ю переїхала до Камбо ле-Бен, де кліматичні умови затримали поступ хвороби. <sub>//[Журнал «Дороговказ. Орган вояцької думки і чину», частина 5–6 (24–25), березень–червень 1965, Торонто, с. 6–7](//books.google.com.ua/books?id=C9ogAQAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF+%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%22)</sub>
  >
  > Все більше давався взнаки поступ хвороби. <sub>//[Літературно-мистецький та громадсько-політичний журнал «Всесвіт», № 1975-8 (560), серпень 1975, видавництво «Радянський письменний», Київ, с. 61](//books.google.com.ua/books?id=K7UrAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF+%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%22)</sub>
  >
  > Через поступ хвороби від кінця 90-х років його участь у політичному житті була обмежена… <sub>//[Журнал «Критика», 2003](//books.google.com.ua/books?id=n-xEAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF+%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%22)</sub>
- прогрес хвороби:

  > Рік 1897 накинувся на Франка, як він про це сам скаже, наче два пси на діда на перелазі: виборами і хворобою. Різкий кон'юктивіт і дальший прогрес хвороби. <sub>//У декількох місцях, зокрема [журнал «Жовтень за 1980](//books.google.com.ua/books?id=oPpDAAAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81+%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%22) і [журнал «Дукля» за 1981](//books.google.com.ua/books?id=615gAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81+%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%22)</sub>
  >
  > Результати досліджень вказують, що лікування великими дозами антиоксиданту вітаміну Е може уповільнити прогрес хвороби і знизити сферу поширення слабоумства. <sub>//Підручник «Охорона психічного здоров'я в умовах війни», 2017, [з корпусу ГРАК-3](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac3&queryselector=cqlrow&&cql=[lemma%3D%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%22]+[lemma%3D%22%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%22])</sub>
  >
  > Пунікалагін у гранаті сповільнює прогрес хвороб Альцгеймера та Паркінсона, лікуючи запалення в головному мозку. <sub>//[Сайт «Новини Виноградівського району», стаття «Виноградівцям – на замітку: 100 суперкорисних продуктів»](http://vynohradivnews.in.ua/novini/vynohradivshina/14384-vinogradvcyam-na-zamtku-100-superkorisnih-produktv.html), а також [сайт «Новини Тячівського району», стаття «Тячівцям – на замітку: 100 суперкорисних продуктів»](http://tyachivnews.in.ua/novini/tyachyvschina/19213-tyachvcyam-na-zamtku-100-superkorisnih-produktv.html), [з корпусу ГРАК-3](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac3&queryselector=cqlrow&&cql=[lemma%3D%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%22]+[lemma%3D%22%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%22])</sub>
- хвороба поступає:

  > Довгі роки часткового мовчання, з того два останні вже навіть на волі — мабуть час, коли хвороба поступала й нищила творця. <sub>//[«Календар українського народного союзу на 1965 рік», видавництво «Свобода», США, с. 81](//books.google.com.ua/books?id=AkckAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%22)</sub>
  >
  > Хвороба поступала так швидко, що лікарі майже без труду відкрили рака, який вже почав розгризати їй горлянку. <sub>//Софія Яблонська, «Зачарований рік», 1972, [з корпусу ГРАК-3](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac3&queryselector=cqlrow&&cql=[lemma%3D%22%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%22]+[lemma%3D%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%22])</sub>
  >
  > Коли хвороба поступала, мати сказала до нього: «Я думала, що ти будеш на місії і що висповідаєшся». <sub>//Василь Величковський, «Історія Чудотворної ікони Божої Матері Неустанної Помочі», 1967–1973, [з корпусу ГРАК-3](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac3&queryselector=cqlrow&&cql=[lemma%3D%22%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%22]+[lemma%3D%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%22])</sub>
  >
  > Він хворів давно, голод, злидні та поневіряння не минули безслідно. Хвороба поступала. 10 жовтня 1968 року Н. Дровняк помер у Фолюші. <sub>//Журнал «Свобода», 2015, № 20, с. 6, [з корпусу ГРАК-3](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac3&queryselector=cqlrow&&cql=[lemma%3D%22%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%22]+[lemma%3D%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%22])</sub>
- хвороба прогресує:

  > Незадовго до судового засідання з'ясувалося, що обидва вони хворі на СНІД і, судячи по тому, як прогресує хвороба, жити їм залишилося мало. <sub>[Анатолій Семенюк, «Король за гратами», 2005, «Надстир'я», Луцьк, с. 122](//books.google.com.ua/books?id=sb0EAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%94+%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%22)</sub>

  Безліч результатів для [«хвороба прогресує»](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%94%22), [«прогресувала хвороба»](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0+%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%22) і [«хвороба прогресувала»](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%22) у «Книгах Google».

  Також 25 результатів для [«<хвороба АБО прогресувати> <хвороба АБО прогресувати>»](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac3&queryselector=cqlrow&&cql=[lemma%3D%22%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%22+|+lemma%3D%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%22]+[lemma%3D%22%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%22+|+lemma%3D%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%22]) у корпусі ГРАК-3.

Отже вживаються всі комбінації. Але наскільки вони стилістично рівноцінні — мені сказати важко. Можливо, «хвороба поступає» є застарілішим чи поетичнішим за «хвороба прогресує». Про це свідчать зокрема:

- помітка «застаріле» у «Словнику української мови» в 11 томах біля відповідного (2-го) значення слова [«поступа́ти»](http://sum.in.ua/s/postupaty) (і там же помітка «переносне»);
- значно більша частота вживання виразу «хвороба прогресує» на практиці.

У той же час щодо іменників «поступ [хвороби]» і «прогрес [хвороби]» я того самого сказати не можу. Навпаки, мені особисто здається, що «поступ» до «хвороби» пасує більше, через надто оптимістичну конотацію слова «прогрес» — але це нічим не підтверджується. На практиці обидва варіанти з іменниками вживаються майже однаково (4 «поступи» vs 3 «прогреси»).

Post Scriptum: Також, як влучно [зазначив Yellow Sky](/q/2820#comment5088_2820), є «хвороба розвивається»/«розвиток хвороби». «Хвороба розвивається», наскільки я можу судити, за частотою вжитку на рівні із «хвороба прогресує» (тобто із вживанішим варіантом). А «розвиток хвороби» переважає за кількістю вживань і «поступ», і «прогрес» (обидва Ваші варіанти) разом.

Answer (score 0):

З СУМ-11

> **[ПРОГРЕСУВАТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/proghresuvaty) 1.** Переходити на вищий ступінь розвитку; іти по
>   шляху прогресу; протилежне регресувати. 
>   **2.** Поступово зростати, збільшуватися, посилюватися.
>
> **[ПОСТУПАТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/postupaty)** **1.** *неперех., заст.* Іти, ступати. **2.** *неперех., перен., заст.* Досягати вищого ступеня,
>   рівня в процесі розвитку; **3.** *неперех., розм., рідко.* Влаштовуватися на роботу.

Із словника синонімів

> ***[ПРОГРЕСУВАТИ](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8)*** ЗБІ́ЛЬШУВАТИСЯ *(доходити вищого ступеня вияву)*, ПОСИ́ЛЮВАТИСЯ,   ПІДСИ́ЛЮВАТИСЯ, НАРОСТА́ТИ, НАРО́ЩУВАТИСЯ,
>   СИЛЬНІ́ШАТИ, ПРОГРЕСУВА́ТИ, ПРИБУВА́ТИ, ПОБІ́ЛЬШУВАТИСЯ *рідше*,
>   ПРИБІ́ЛЬШУВАТИСЯ *розм.*, ПРИБАВЛЯ́ТИСЯ *розм.*, ПРИБІЛЬША́ТИСЯ
>   *діал.* - *Док.*: збі́льшитися, поси́литися, підси́литися, нарости́, посильні́шати, прибу́ти, побі́льшитися, прибі́льшитися, приба́витися.

В цьомуж словнику для слова "поступати" має синоніми лише за першим значенням.

> ***[ПОСТУПАТИ](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8)*** ВСТУПА́ТИ[УСТУПА́ТИ] *(в члени якоїсь організації, навчальний заклад і т. ін.)*, ПОСТУПА́ТИ, ІТИ́,
>   ПРИЄ́ДНУВАТИСЯ, ЗАПИ́СУВАТИСЯ. - *Док.:* вступи́ти[уступи́ти],
>   поступи́ти, піти́, приєдна́тися, записа́тися.
>
> ІТИ́[ЙТИ] *(роблячи кроки, пересуватися в просторі)*, ПРОСТУВА́ТИ,
>   ПРЯМУВА́ТИ, СТУПА́ТИ, МАНДРУВА́ТИ *розм.*, ТО́ПАТИ *розм.*, ТУПЦЮВА́ТИ
>   *розм.*, ТУ́ПЦЯТИ *розм.*, ТУ́ПАТИ *розм.*, ГРЯСТИ́ *уроч.*, *поет.*, ПОСТУПА́ТИСЯ *розм.*, ПОСТУПА́ТИ *заст.*; КРОКУВА́ТИ, МАРШИРУВА́ТИ
>   [МАРШУВА́ТИ] *розм.* (перев. широким, розміреним кроком); ВИСТУПА́ТИ
>   (поважно, з гідністю)

Оскільки ***поступати*** має лише одне спільне значення (2) з ***прогресувати***, варто розмежовувати вживання даних слів. Отже, правильно ***прогресування хвороби/прогрес хвороби.***

Comment: Запитання автора, хоч воно доволі нечітко сформульоване, мені здається, стосується в першу чергу дієслів (а не іменників). А ці дієслова, хоч вони і є синонімами в одному зі значень, але: по-перше, підходить лише одне зі значень слова _поступати_, а в нього є й інші, по-друге, потрібне значення в слові _поступати_ є переносним і **застарілим** — тому я не впевнений, що ці слова абсолютно взаємозамінні. Крім того я ніколи не чув «хвороба поступає» — хоча, може, це моя необізнаність.

Comment: @Sasha так, я не правильно зрозуміла питання. Найближчим часом виправлю відповідь.

Comment: Дякую. Дуже радий, що Ви зреагували. Бо іноді трапляється, що люди щось написали й пішли (й уже нічого не зробиш).

Comment: @Sasha сподіваюсь, так правильно?

Comment: Перепрошую, я не мав на увазі, що у Вас щось неправильно написано. (Я сам не знаю, чи можна використовувати дієслово «поступає» до іменника «хвороба» — я такого не чув, але це не значить, що це заборонено.) Я лише хотів сказати, що попередня відповідь, здається, не відповідала на запитання.

Comment: Я зняв (свій) «мінус», але «плюс» теж поки не поставив, бо (може як не достататньо уважно прочитав, перепрошую, ще ввечері гляну уважніше, але) мені поки що відповідь не прояснила і не переконала остаточно.

Comment: Трішки подумав: особисто я бачу, що де-факто люди кажуть [«поступ хвороби»](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22поступ+хвороби%22), але не кажуть «хвороба поступає». Але чому так — не знаю.

Comment: Upd.: А, ні, [«хвороба поступала»](//books.google.com.ua/books?id=AkckAQAAIAAJ&q=%22хвороба+поступала%22) теж кажуть (і [в інших формах](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac3&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=[lemma%3D%22хвороба%22]+[lemma%3D%22поступати%22])). Хоча чи це настільки ж стилістично нейтральна форма (як і «хвороба прогресує») (може, це якось дуже поетично) — я не знаю.

Comment: Важливий нюанс: я сам не мовознавець. В мене зовсім інша освіта. Ви, мабуть, краще за мене знаєте, як правильно. Мій перший комент був лише про те, що: (а) Ви, НМД, змішували застосовність іменників із застосовністю дієслів (адже цілком може статися, що якийсь іменник до чогось підходить, а відповідне дієслово — ні, або навпаки; тобто із застосовності іменника в загальному випадку не завжди випливає застовосність дієслова, і навпаки); (б) Ви наводили статтю зі словника синонімів як аргумент, але там наводять не лише повні синоніми («тупцювати» там теж є); (в) Ви проігн. «заст.» **<продовжу…>**

Comment: **<…продовжую>** Але це не означає, що Ваш перший варіант відповіді був неправильний. Скажу чесно — я сам не знаю, як правильно відповісти. Просто аргументи в ньому для мене були непереконливими, лише це я мав на увазі (а не що висновок не відповідав дійсності; висновок, може, й правильний був — я не знаю, але аргументи недостатні, НМД).

Comment: @Sasha якщо розглядати дієслова *поступати* і *прогресувати* - вони не синоніми, а іменники *поступ* і *прогрес* - синоніми.

Comment: Мені здається, «поступати» і «прогресувати» — теж часткові синоніми (дуже часткові), але можу помилятися.